# Arcpy Pythonaddins Equivalent of arcpy.GetParameterAsText

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, python-addin

I've build a neat little search arcpy script. The user opens any mxd, zooms to a location, chooses a corporate fGDB, and runs the tool. The user gets a list of all the populated feature class that intersects the current extent. Later I aim to write a process that the user can choose which layers they want to add. However I digress. I'm looking at embedding the arcpy into an addin, my first issue is learning what the equivalent of a arcpy.GetParameterAsText is, as I want the user to specify the work-space they need to interrogate.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
class ButtonClass1(object):
"""Implementation for AddIn_Test4_addin.button (Button)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False
def onClick(self):
    ################## MAP DOCUMENT DATA FRAME EXTENT

    StagingGDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    #StagingGDB = "C:\\Data\\Projects\\SearchTool\\CorpData1.gdb"
    arcpy.env.workspace = StagingGDB
    ExtentFC = StagingGDB +"\\ExtentFC"

    ############ Clean Up & Pre Check
    if arcpy.Exists(ExtentFC):
        arcpy.Delete_management(ExtentFC)

    ################## MAP DOCUMENT DATA FRAME EXTENT
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    currentExtent = df.extent

    ################## EXTENT FC
    pnt1 = arcpy.Point(currentExtent.XMin , currentExtent.YMin)
    pnt2 = arcpy.Point(currentExtent.XMax , currentExtent.YMin)
    pnt3 = arcpy.Point(currentExtent.XMax , currentExtent.YMax)
    pnt4 = arcpy.Point(currentExtent.XMin , currentExtent.YMax)
    array = arcpy.Array()
    array.add(pnt1)
    array.add(pnt2)
    array.add(pnt3)
    array.add(pnt4)
    array.add(pnt1)
    DisplayExtent = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(DisplayExtent , StagingGDB ,"ExtentFC", "", "", "")
    pass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe sys.argv ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pythonaddins` is limited in getting parameters directly from a user that are not associated with the table of contents as `pythonaddins` is mainly a way to offer python developers a way to interact with user events. That being said the main mechanism for a developer to get parameters from a user in the same way as `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` is through `pythonaddins.OpenFileDialog`. Just like get `GetParameterAsText`, `pythonaddins.OpenFileDialog` takes the user input and returns a string to the developer.
So in your case you could prompt the user with `OpenFileDialog` and then use the `os` and `glob` modules in python to further get at which files you want. Like this:

```
inFileGDB = pythonaddins.OpenDialog('Open File Geodatabase',False, r'','Open GDB')
```

Another option would be to have the user select a layer in the table of contents that lives in the file geodatabase of interest and click your button. Behind the scenes you would use `pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()` to access further information about the file, i.e. the path to the geodatabase that it lives in. Like this:

```
    lyr = pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()
    lyrDescribe = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
```